# How to calculate the Laplace transform of $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k}\delta (t-k)$?

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

On my midterm, I had the following question:

> Calculate the Laplace transform of $$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k}\delta (t-k)$$

I was wondering how I should calculate it. I know that the transform would be $\dfrac{e^s}{1+e^s}$, and we were given the hint that we may need to use

$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a^{k} = \dfrac{1}{1-a}$$

for $|a|<1$. My original thought was to write out the sum, which would become

$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k}\delta (t-k) = [\delta(t)-\delta(t-1)] + [\delta(t-2)+\delta(t-3)]+\cdots$$

Then I know the Laplace transform of the pairs would be

$$[1-e^{-s}]+[e^{-2s}+e^{-3s}]+\cdots$$

and then group the positive terms ($\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}e^{-2ks}$) and the negative terms ($-\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}e^{-(2k+1)s}$) and use the hint to get the final result, but I am unable to get the correct answer. I was wondering if my approach is correct or perhaps there is another way to calculate the Laplace transform?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have $(1-e^{-s}) + (e^{-2s}+e^{-3s}) + (e^{-4s}-e^{-5s})$...

This comes out to $(1+e^{-2s}+e^{-4s})....+(-e^{-s}+e^{-3s}-e^{-5s}...)$

This can be rewritten as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-e^{-2s}}-\frac{e^{-s}}{1+e^{-2s}}$.

Now, you have $\displaystyle \frac{1+e^{-2s}}{1-e^{-4s}}-\frac{e^{-s}(1-e^{-2s})}{1-e^{-4s}}$.

Now combine them to get $\displaystyle \frac{1-e^{-s}+e^{-2s}+e^{-3s}}{1-e^{-4s}}=\frac{1+e^{-s}+e^{-2s}+e^{-3s}}{1-e^{-4s}}-\frac{2e^{-s}}{1-e^{-4s}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-s}}-\frac{2e^{-s}}{1-e^{-4s}}$.

Comment: Why not simply use $a = - e^{-s}$? Why split the sum in two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\mathcal{L} \left\{ \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k}\delta (t-k) \right\}
= \int_0^\infty \left( \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k}\delta (t-k) \right) e^{-st} \, dt
= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k} \int_0^\infty \delta (t-k) e^{-st} \, dt \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k} e^{-ks}
= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-e^{-s})^{k}
= \frac{1}{1-\left(-e^{-s}\right)}
= \frac{1}{1+e^{-s}}
= \frac{e^s}{e^s+1}
$$